S3 JS client PUT Error - TypeError: t.getUTCFullYear is not a function
I am getting the following error when PUTing a file to S3 using the javascript client.
TypeError: t.getUTCFullYear is not a function
 at dateToUtcString (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/@smithy+smithy-client@3.2.0/node_modules/@smithy/smithy-client/dist-cjs/index.js:590:21)
 at value (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-sdk+client-s3@3.637.0/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-s3/dist-cjs/index.js:2730:87)
 at applyInstruction (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/@smithy+smithy-client@3.2.0/node_modules/@smithy/smithy-client/dist-cjs/index.js:1104:27)
 at map (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/@smithy+smithy-client@3.2.0/node_modules/@smithy/smithy-client/dist-cjs/index.js:1045:5)
 at mapWithFilter (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/@smithy+smithy-client@3.2.0/node_modules/@smithy/smithy-client/dist-cjs/index.js:1065:10)
 at map (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/@smithy+smithy-client@3.2.0/node_modules/@smithy/smithy-client/dist-cjs/index.js:1035:14)
 at serializer (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-sdk+client-s3@3.637.0/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-s3/dist-cjs/index.js:2716:44)
 at next (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/@smithy+middleware-serde@3.0.3/node_modules/@smithy/middleware-serde/dist-cjs/index.js:64:25)
 at next (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-sdk+middleware-sdk-s3@3.635.0/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-sdk-s3/dist-cjs/index.js:615:12)
 at <anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/@smithy+middleware-endpoint@3.1.0/node_modules/@smithy/middleware-endpoint/dist-cjs/index.js:206:12)

Here is the code:
const s3Client = new S3Client({
  credentials: fromEnv(),
  region: process.env.REGION,
});

const params = {
  Bucket: process.env.FILES_BUCKET_NAME,
  Key: "files/" + key,
  Body: contents,
  ContentType: contentType,
  Metadata: {
    filename: filename,
  },
  ACL: "private",
};

if (expires) {
  params.Expires = expires;
}

const command = new PutObjectCommand(params);
try {
  await s3Client.send(command);
} catch (error) {
  console.error("Error uploading file:", error);
  throw error;
}

I am using v3.637.0 of @aws-sdk/client-s3 and @aws-sdk/credential-providers on Node.js 18 runtime.
I don't have any leads.  What could be going wrong?

How is the generated? are you passing a date anywhere?
